# UIButton's image shows up faint?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm trying to change `UIButton's` image to white and set a background color when it's pressed to end up with something like this:

[image]

I'm setting the button's image to a white one and setting it's background color like this:

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "Food_White")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .highlighted)
button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.gray, size: CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)), for: .highlighted)
```

But when I press the button the white image barely shows:

[image: button]

Does anybody know how to make the image less faint?

Comment: What button type are you using? Try creating the button with `.custom` type instead of the default `.system` :)

Comment: Oh that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the default button type when creating them?

Try creating the button with `.custom` type instead of the default `.system`